# Why Hibernate adds new role instead of adding role id in foreign key column?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, api, hibernate

In my spring boot project I use PostgreSQL and Hibernate. I created 2 tables for user and separate table for role, create entities:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_account")
public class UserAccount {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "birthday")
    private LocalDateTime birthday;

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private UserRole role;
}
```

and for role:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class UserRole {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private RoleName name;
}
```

Code of controller:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "")
UserAccountDTO create(@RequestBody UserAccount user) {
    return userService.create(user);
}
```

UserService method create():

```java
    @Override
    public UserAccountDTO create(UserAccount user) {
        UserAccount recordedUser = userRepository.save(user);
    
        return modelMapper.map(recordedUser, UserAccountDTO.class);
    }
```

UserRepository(based on Spring-Data JPA):

```java
    @Repository
    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserAccount, Integer> {
    }
```

dto:

```java
public class UserAccountDTO {
    private Integer id;
    private String username;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private LocalDateTime birthday;
    private UserRole role;
}
```

In table role I already created 2 roles - ADMIN, CLIENT(default values). So I want to implement functionality when you can add user and simply write role_id in column which refers to role table as one-to-one. So during insert it shoild add record with new user with role id key which refers to necessary role-record
I have to send post requests I have to send such JSON:

```json
{
    "firstName": "test1",
    "lastName": "user",
    "password": "test",
    "username": "test_mail@mail.loc",
    "role": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "CLIENT"
    }
}
```

Hibernate creates user recored, but also it adds new role record with name CLIENT and this is wrong. Why and what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share your code where you persist the roles and users ?

Comment: @b.GHILAS sure. updated code

Comment: Tried your code locally, it works fine, which database you use ?

Comment: @b.GHILAS postgres

Comment: Can you add the code for your `userService` (especially the `create()` method)? Thanks!

Comment: @JoãoDias added

Comment: @SamFisher how could be possible that role had been saved if role with id 2 already exists? Does not role table have a primary key?

Comment: @galaxy good question. table role has column id(which is primary key). hibernate creates new record on role table every time. if I specify role: {id: 2} then it creates record writes null in name column. if I specify name it creates role with this name. may be this is because of (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)?

Comment: @SamFisher if you specify id role of 2 there should be a primary key constraint violation. I don't get when you say writes null in name column.

Comment: @SamFisher yes I think the cascade is the problem, you didn't include this in your post the first time, this is why it works fine for me. Either delete the cascade or use the solution of João Dias below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you are indeed including a role with an ID in your request. The problem is that this role is just a regular object and not an entity that Hibernate knows or that is related in any way with data already in the database.

Having written this, you will need to get the corresponding role from the database and set it in `UserAccount` you want to create. This means that you need to update your `UserService.create()` method accordingly:

```java
@Override
public UserAccountDTO create(UserAccount user) {
    UserRole userRole = userRoleRepository.findByName(user.getNam()); // I would suggest getting it by name instead of by ID
    user.setRole(userRole);
    UserAccount recordedUser = userRepository.save(user);

    return modelMapper.map(recordedUser, UserAccountDTO.class);
}
```

---

As a side note, just like you have a DTO for the response, you should also have a DTO for the request. Using Entities as response or request in your Controller is a bad practice and should be avoided. I would suggest you create the following DTO for the request:

```java
public class UserAccountCreationRequestDto {
    private String userName;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String password;
    private LocalDateTime birthday;
    private RoleName roleName;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. it helped me. but appeared new question. now I receive requestDTO. I need to create new user account object and map fields from dto to it and map role. is that a good practice?

Comment: Yes, it is, using Entities in your Controllers as response or request should be avoided at all costs. See your entities as the core of your business. These are the classes you use in your services and while doing some serious business logic. All the other classes (so-called DTOs) are used to get data and send data to the consumers of your API. This also means that you decouple your public model from your domain model, meaning that you can change any of those without having to modify the other (of course the mapping needs to be changed, but that is hidden from the consumers of your API).